# Как получить данные из массива данных в php?

Tags: php

Не могу получить значение **value_sum**

`var_dump( $result );` отдает следующее:

```
array(1) {
   [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["value_sum"]=>
    string(4) "2750"
  }
}
```

Как получить 2750?

up: получил вот так:

```
$new = array_slice($result, 0, 2);
$first = array_shift($new);  
print $first['value_sum'];
```

Можно ли короче?

Спасибо!

Comment: Уберите ответ из вопроса и оформите его как ответ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так короче: `echo $result[0]['value_sum'];`